# How to get multilist , dropdown list field value of an item using PowerShell query

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am looking to extract the multilist , dropdown list field value of an item using PowerShell query.

```
    $item = Get-Item -Path master -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

$rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["My checklist field name"]

$selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()

foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
    $selectedItem.DisplayName
}
```

Error I am getting is You cannot call a method on a null valued expression

Comment: What have you tried?  There is nothing special about getting a field value from either of these

Comment: $item = Get-Item -Path master -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

$rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["My checklist field name"]

$selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()

foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
    $selectedItem.DisplayName
}

Error I am getting is You cannot call a method on a null valued expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `$item.Fields["FieldName"}` to `Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField`:

```
$multilistField = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["FieldName"]

$multilistItems = $multilistField.GetItems()

foreach($multilistItem in $multilistItems){
    # do whatever you want with item from multilist
}
```

---

**EDIT AFTER OP CHANGED THEIR QUESTION**

The error you get means that one of your variables is `null`.

Check which one is that. It can be either

- `$item` itself
- or `$item.Fields["My checklist field name"]`

Comment: Hi @Marek , Thanks for your input, It really helped me solve the problem.